# How can i solve this ERROR? process begin: create process when compilation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

> 12:36:45: Running steps for project omim... 12:36:45: Configuration
>   unchanged, skipping qmake step. 12:36:45: Starting:
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
>
> Makefile:106: recipe for target 'sub-3party-make_first' failed
>   process_begin:
>   CreateProcess(C:\Users\IIGO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\make9928-1.bat,
>   C:\Users\IIGO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\make9928-1.bat, ...) failed. make
>   (e=5): Acceso denegado.
>
> mingw32-make: [sub-3party-make_first] Error 5 12:36:51: The process
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project omim (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.0
>   MinGW 32bit) When executing step "Make"

Comment: You could explain better, your question is unclear.

Comment: According to some things I observe the problem is permissions, try to run as an administrator.

Comment: When I start a repository with Qt and execute the project I get this error

Comment: Did you run it as an admin?

Comment: Yes and I get the same error

Comment: You could explain the steps you've taken.

Comment: I start Qt, then i open a repository and run the project.

Comment: Have you started Qt? or  Have you started QtCreator? What repository do you mean?

Comment: I have started Qt creator. I have a Git repository